# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction'?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the code i use to insert record. Whenever there is insert error , The subscriber table auto - inc number will still increase even i have roll back? What is the problem?  **I just want the auto increment number not add when error occur**.thanks a lot for help .

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);
$conn->beginTransaction();
try {

    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];


    $query="INSERT INTO subscriber (Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate) VALUES (?,?,?,CURDATE())";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $FirstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $LastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $conn->rollBack();
    die ($e->getMessage()."<a href='addSub.php'>Back</a>");
    }

$conn->beginTransaction();
try {
    $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query="INSERT INTO list_sub (SubID,ListID) VALUES ('',$_SESSION[ListID])";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    $conn->rollBack();
    die ($e->getMessage()."<a href='addSub.php'>Back</a>");
    }

$conn = null;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing line numbers in your code, its hard to *know* but you commit your transaction at the end of the first try-catch block, and then proceed without starting a new transaction in your second try-catch block.

Add `$conn->beginTransaction();` at the beginning of your second try-catch block.

EDIT -
You mention "I just want the auto increment number not add when error occur".  You should not rely on the auto-increment feature to generate a "gapless" sequence of numbers.

Comment: it doesn't show that error message again , however, it does not roll back . The subscriber table still increase the auto increment number whenever there is error

Comment: It should auto-increment - that is expected behavior.

Comment: that means I have to use some sql statement such as 'set table auto-inc number = x -1 ' in my php code to roll it back? Thank you~

Comment: Correct - you would have to set it explicitly.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of roll back?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if while in the middle of a transaction, someone else is also starting a transaction.  You rollback, they continue.  What should happen to their auto-incremented column?

Answer (score 5):

PDO's auto-commit is probably enabled, and it's causing a problem when you try to rollback, since it has already committed.  You can use [PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) to disable this behavior:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);
```

Comment: thanks i put it under  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); , is that ok?

Comment: @user782104: Yes, that should be fine.  Just remember that with this setting disabled, you will have to manually commit every query.

Answer (score 1):

When running under apache (or perhaps other mechanism that does connection pooling), you may need to check and ensure that you have not got persistent connections in use.

This is because when connection pooling is in effect, you cannot guarantee that the call to `->commit()` winds up on the same connection on which you called `->beginTransaction()`.

This kind of situation manifests in cases where you are using multiple database handles to perform multiple queries, and only one series of queries belong in a transaction, which you have dutifully bound to a specific database handle (variable). However, underneath you, the pooling connection manager may be sending your queries among any available connection so long as you haven't specified "exclusive" use by disabling persistence on one of the handles.

In my case, I was performing a transaction with a series of steps. Due to the code being composed of functions to accomplish specific tasks in the transaction, some of the functions would spin-off a separate database connection to perform some related query (e.g verify ownership of an asset identified in a table row). Running in an apache environment, I would get this error 'There is no active transaction', and in addition, the rollBack() call appeared to be ineffective -- the changes were committed even thought he call to commit reported an error.

Took me a while to narrow it down to persistent connections. Turning off connection pooling on the handle for which I was performing a transaction made things work the way I expected.