# How to turn this SQL Query into PDO Transaction without Errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this SQL Query:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
  VALUES('alpha', 'omega');
INSERT INTO profiles (userid, cv, website) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'some cv things', 'www.domain.com');
COMMIT;
```

And I want to use `PDO` instead of the `MYSQL` Transcation so I can pull the `catched error` Because I don't get it from the `MYSQL` Transaction, What I've tried was

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
  INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    VALUES('alpha', 'omega');
  INSERT INTO profiles (userid, cv, website) 
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'some cv things', 'www.domain.com');
 ");
 $stmt->execute();
 $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 $dbh->rollback();
 throw $e;
}
```

But I kept getting this Error

```
Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction . . . PDO->rollBack() #1 {main} thrown
```

The reocrds were `INSERT`ed into the Table, But the error kept being shown too.

I've tried using `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);` but still got the Error message.

Then tried to remove `try-catch` and kept the `Query` with the PDO Transactions and got this Error message

```
Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction . . . PDO->commit() #1 {main} thrown
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418663/uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-there-is-no-active-transaction)

Comment: @Chris Tried both of them but didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris didn't *hide* the problem, Which is the error message.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you're running 2 queries via `prepare`. Split it into two calls to `prepare` or `exec`, or even `query`. Your parameters are already clean, there's no need to prepare anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not passing any params do it like this:

```
try {
    $stmt = $dbh->exec('
        INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`)
        VALUES("alpha", "omega");
    ');

    $stmt_2 = $dbh->exec('
         INSERT INTO `profiles` (`userid`, `cv`, `website`) 
         VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), "some cv things", "www.domain.com");
    ');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $dbh->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

this will execute the query - you don't need to prepare because you're already escaping your strings so a simple `$dbh->exec` will do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

You're `throw`ing the exception in your error handler:

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
 $dbh->rollback();
 throw $e;  // <-- right here
}
```

That will cause the exception to keep going until it's handled, and [if it's not handled it will throw a fatal error](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching [catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch) block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "*Uncaught Exception ...*" message, unless a handler has been defined with [set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

If your exception handler is completely handling the exception you should remove that line.

Comment: What does "removed the entire `try-catch`" mean? You removed those whole blocks, including the code inside them so all that's left from the question is `$dbh->beginTransaction();`? Then I can't help you because I can't see any other code.

Comment: removed `try{} catch(PDOException $e){throw $e;}` not anything else inside.